# Xlib: extension "GLX" missing - with an NVIDIA card and on-board graphics

Tags: xorg, graphics, intel-graphics

I have a machine with an NVIDIA GeForce which I *don't* use for display purposes (i.e. the monitor is not connected to it), and some lackluster  on-board graphics chip. (Below you'll find the relevant `lshw` listing.)

My X sessions work just fine; but when most of my X apps (which require any sort of fancy GFX or a toolkit) run, they emit the following error message:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

My question is: How can I make my apps notice the non-NVIDIA GLX library and use it (without removing the NVIDIA card and without switching the monitor to its output ports of course)?

I'm using Debian/Linux Stretch 64bit, kernel version 4.2.6, with LXDE.

Output of `lshw -c display`:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK106 [GeForce GTX 650 Ti Boost]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:e8000000-e9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Output of `glxinfo`:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

Output of `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep glx`:

```
[    19.287] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    19.787] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    22.727] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
```

Additional information:

- I do not have the `glx-alternative-nvidia` package installed.
- If I boot from a live-image USB of Devuan ASCII, the problem does *not* manifest.
- If I create an `xorg.conf` using `Xorg :1 -configure`, [this](http://paste.debian.net/1073400/) is what it produces (2 'Device' sections, one associated with the `intel` driver, another with `nouveau`); but if I comment-out the nouveau section and try running Xorg with that configuration - it won't load, [saying](http://paste.debian.net/1073347/) it can't find any screens.

Comment: The solution for me was removing `bumblebee` and installing `nvidia-bumblebee` (on Debian Jessie, using the backports gfx packages).

Answer (score 9):

I arrived here after installing `nvidia-current` from the package repository, and got [stuck on a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop). I looked at the log on `~/.xsession-errors` and found the mentioned error:

`Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".`

I already had uninstalled `nvidia-current` and the problem persisted. I also didn't have `glx-alternative-nvidia` installed. As a last resort, I simply uninstalled everything from `nvidia` on my Ubuntu (including CUDA stuff), and it worked after the restart.

Comment: Sorry for not replying to this before. I don't have `nvidia-current` installed, nor, in fact, any `nvidia-` package. But I do have the latest CUDA installed, with the accompanying driver (the manual installer from nvidia). I know that's an ugly way to do things, but I do need the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

First identify which glx module is in use:

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep glx
[     3.622] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     3.624] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     3.705] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
```

In Debian 8 Jessie my solution was to remove `glx-alternative-nvidia` package. So after reboot:

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep glx
[     3.581] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     3.582] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     3.592] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"

$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Desktop
```

Comment: I'm actually only getting the X.Org founction module to begin with... see edit.

Comment: And how do you remove it? It's not listed on my `apt-get` packages.

Comment: @VillasV you need to enable `contrib` repository to see it. And probably you don't even have it installed, and thus your cause of missing glx extension error is different.

Comment: Minor nitpick: why do you say `cat file | grep pattern`? Why not `grep pattern file`?

Comment: @Timo, just a personal preference. In the shell history I find it easier to see how the pattern evolved if it goes last.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow let this conversation slip. So, in the same situation basically. I get the same `Xorg.0.log` lines as you, but `glxinfo` gives the same error messages as before. And I don't have `glx-alternative-nvidia` installed.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by uninstalling glx-alternative-nvidia

```
apt-get remove glx-alternative-nvidia
```

Comment: I don't even have the `glx-alternative-nvidia` package installed...

Answer (score 2):

I had issues after upgrading Debian 9 after clicking the reboot to upgrade prompt.

When installing initially I followed the steps found in the wiki https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers

The important ones for me were...

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get install -t stretch-backports nvidia-driver
```

Then performed a reboot

Answer (score 1):

[Install OpenGL](https://askubuntu.com/a/937531/279479) in your computer, then as [mentioned here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1276123), add the following to your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Files"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/nvidia-VERSION/xorg"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
EndSection
```

(Replace `nvidia-VERSION` with your directory name)
This worked for me.

Comment: I don't have the first directory. In fact, I don't even have an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` for some reason.

Comment: You can have it created for you with `sudo nvidia-xconfig`

Comment: @GabrielFair: I absolutely should _not_ do that. This will likely make my nVIDIA card be used for X; and even if it won't - it is conceptually inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Got it "extension "GLX" missing" when I "dist-upgraded" my debian (8 -> 9). The solution was pretty simple.

## Download your driver installer on NVIDIA

```
service lightdm stop
#(ALT+F1) + your credentials
sudo nvidia-installer --uninstall
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.102-custom.run #my vga GT218M [GeForce 310M]
```

After the installer did its job, the GLX went back.

ps: If you user repos, I think an dpkg-reconfigure "driver_package_name" would do the same.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this will make X use the nVIDIA GLX module. Which is not what I want, as I'm not using my GPU for display purposes.